# Can you set a default alert time other than those suggested by Calendar?

Tags: mac, calendar, sonoma

I frequently create an all-day event (or time event) and like to have a reminder set to the day before at 3pm and the day of at 6 am.  I can do that via the custom feature, but it takes a lot of clicks to do with each event.  If I could set a default to something other than what Apple sets, that would be nice. I am using an M3 Macbook Pro on Sonoma.